# How to get which of dynamically made checkboxes are checked?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got section in my program where it lists all units from the database which is saved in a file and make a item in a ListBox for every of them, which looks like this:

```
 public static void populateFormatedUnitListBox(Database db, ListBox lb)
    {
        lb.Items.Clear();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var unit in db.units)
        {
            if (unit == null) break;
            var item = new StackPanel();
            item.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            item.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            item.Width = lb.Width-5;
            item.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            var row1 = new StackPanel();
            row1.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;
            row1.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;

            var checkbox = new CheckBox();
            checkbox.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
            checkbox.Name = "UnitCheck" + index;
            index++;

            item.Children.Add(checkbox);

            var text = new TextBlock();
            text.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            text.Text = unit.name;
            text.FontSize = 10;

            row1.Children.Add(text);


            var row2 = new TextBlock();
            row2.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            row2.Text = " 0 / " + unit.wordCount + " (0%)";
            row2.FontSize = 10;
            row1.Children.Add(row2);

            item.Children.Add(row1);

            lb.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

How can I get some kind of list which of them are checked or how to check individually everyone of them? Or maybe can I somehow give them some IDs?

I'm learning C# and I'm complete novice in terms of WPF, so I would really appreciate maybe not even direct solution, but some hints what kind of techniques I should get into to solve it.

Comment: Consider using MVVM, as it makes this use case a *ton* easier.

Comment: `Consider also, reading up on the Controls` class as well as how to use `foreach(Control ctr in Controls)` for example in order to check which ones are checked you will need to iterate over the `Controls`

Comment: poor programming in WPF, this could be easily solved with `DataTemplates`, `Triggers`, `DataTriggers`. You should read up on these topics. Reason why I am calling this poor programming is because rather than looking into the actual problem we need to study your code and figure what you're aiming for. if you would use MvvM this  problem would never occur with aforementioned key words. HTH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BradleyDotNET suggested MVVM **should be your choice**.
Anyway the fastest (*but not the best*) solution to your problem can be the `Tag` property of `CheckBox` control.

You can use it in order to "store" a link to your db object (you call it "unit"). Take a look:

```
var checkbox = new CheckBox();
checkbox.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
checkbox.Name = "UnitCheck" + index;
checkbox.Tag = unit.ID;
index++;
```

where `unit.ID` is a unique identifier of your object.
So you can find which checkbox is checked just using a foreach cycle and checking the `Tag` property you can retrieve which unit object/objects was/were selected.

Comment: Thank you! That was a solution I was looking for! 
About MVVM - I'm trying first to get used to C# and WPF, learning all common techniques and controls, then I'll try to apply MVVM style to all of that, even at a cost of rebuilding whole application, because as I said earlier, I'm beginning with these languages.